# Why does this custom configuration provider incorrectly bind array elements?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, app-config

I am preparing to write a custom configuration provider in .NET Core 2.2. My custom configuration provider extends the ConfigurationProvider class. It sets the Data property to a dictionary representing an object containing a string array. When I attempt to bind the built configuration to the class the array values end up being null. When I use the same dictionary with the InMemoryCollection provider, the array values are bound properly.

```
public class TestConfigProvider : ConfigurationProvider
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Data = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"array:entries:0", "value0"},
                    {"array:entries:1", "value1"}
                };
        }
    }
    public class TestConfigSource : IConfigurationSource
    {
        public IConfigurationProvider Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            return new TestConfigProvider();
        }
    }
    public static class TestConfigExtensions
    {
        public static IConfigurationBuilder AddCustomConfig(this IConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.Add(new TestConfigSource());
        }
    }

    public class ArrayExample
    {
        public string[] Entries { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, string> _data = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"array:entries:0", "value0"},
                    {"array:entries:1", "value1"}
                };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IConfiguration config1 = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddCustomConfig()
                .Build();

            IConfiguration config2 = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddInMemoryCollection(_data)
                .Build();

            var test1 = config1.GetSection("array").Get<ArrayExample>();
            var test2 = config2.GetSection("array").Get<ArrayExample>();

            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test1)); // {"Entries":[null,null,null,null,null]}
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test2)); // {"Entries":["value0","value1","value2","value4","value5"]}
        }
    }
```

I expected both configs to bind the array values.

I am able to pull out the individual values using the index operator on the configuration object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reviewing the source for [`MemoryConfigurationProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Configuration/Config/src/MemoryConfigurationProvider.cs#L13) and seeing how they populate the provided initial data

```
public MemoryConfigurationProvider(MemoryConfigurationSource source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    }

    _source = source;

    if (_source.InitialData != null)
    {
        foreach (var pair in _source.InitialData)
        {
            Data.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

by populating `Data` as apposed to replacing the entire object.

I did the same in `TestConfigProvider`

```
public class TestConfigProvider : ConfigurationProvider {
    public override void Load() {
        var initialData = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"array:entries:0", "value0"},
            {"array:entries:1", "value1"}
        };

        foreach (var pair in initialData) {
            Data.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

And got similar results to using the in-memory provider, with binding behaving as desired by populating the array values when testing

```
[TestClass]
public class CustomConfigurationTests {
    public static Dictionary<string, string> _data = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"array:entries:0", "value0"},
                {"array:entries:1", "value1"}
            };

    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_Bind_Array() {
        //Arrange
        IConfiguration config1 = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddCustomConfig()
            .Build();

        IConfiguration config2 = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddInMemoryCollection(_data)
            .Build();

        //Act
        var test1 = config1.GetSection("array").Get<ArrayExample>();
        var test2 = config2.GetSection("array").Get<ArrayExample>();

        //Assert
        test1.Entries.Should().BeEquivalentTo(test2.Entries);
    }
}
```